# 'Ghostscript.NET.GhostscriptLibraryNotInstalledException' in Ghostscript.NET.dll in IIS

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, iis, ghostscript.net

I have Ghostscript installed on my machine(with windows 10) and it is working properly with visual studio IIS Express, but after hosting application on same machine Local IIS, it throws exception *GhostscriptLibraryNotInstalledException*. Please help me to find issue, thanks in advance.

Comment: Is the library installed?

Comment: yes it is working with iis express on same machine, could you please tell me if any other library required?

Comment: I copy the file locally for my iis, also make sure you have the right bitness, ie you are publishing the right bitness to what you are using in IIS express

Comment: Possible duplicate of [GhostscriptLibraryNotInstalledException running under 32-bit process requires native library](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34454108/ghostscriptlibrarynotinstalledexception-running-under-32-bit-process-requires-na)

Answer (score 1):

> there is Ghostscript.NET.dll on hosted bin directory

This is not enough, `Ghostscript.NET.dll` is not **the** ghostscript dll. *ghostscript* is under a certain licensing and is not distributed with *Ghostscript.NET*, you need `gsdll32.dll` or `gsdll64.dll` in your published bin directory or have it installed in such a way that your IIS can find it

I personally, (to make it easy) just publish with the dll included

Comment: Thank you very much, I tried everything to run on IIS(windows server 2012) but not worked, finally I wrote a windows service for same job, and with windows service it worked very fine.